# Open the "Documents" directory of my app calling the Google Files app

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am developing an app and I should open the "Documents" folder of the directory of my app using the Google Files app (presumably using an intent).
In my app I have a recyclerView that, based on longClick event listener should open a certain directory calling the Google Files App.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Well first show your code to start that Files app. After that we can see what has to be done to let it open in a specified directory. Also tell what you want the user to do once the Files app opens.

Comment: I have implemented already a solution that can rename, delete, send files but my customer want to use Google Files app.
I did not yet started to code.... I guess through an intent. The user should do anything that can do with Google Files app ....like delete, rename, send files

Comment: You can start the FIles app with an intent. Like you can start all apps on your device with an intent.

Comment: You think is possibile? and how to tell it which directory open? have you tried this before?
Which kind of intent?

Comment: There is no requirement for a device to have the Files app, or any file manager for that matter. And, there is no standard `Intent` action for "view a directory in a file manager" defined in the Android SDK.

Comment: Start an app is possible. I dont know how to tell the files app to open in a specified directory.  Or maybe i know but i have no code at hand now.

Comment: CommonsWare...You are telling that it is not possible? at the moment I am opening calling Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT and doing several things based on "onRequestCode" and onActivityResult. But the does not show the icons for rename, share etc...as in google Files. I think I implement a similar solution on my recyclerView and put three icons on upper right corner that appear after longClick

Comment: @Houde Barsali, if you want to call someone then use an @ before the name.

Comment: @CommonsWare...You are telling that it is not possible? at the moment I am opening calling Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT and doing several things based on "onRequestCode" and onActivityResult. But the does not show the icons for rename, share etc...as in google Files. I think I implement a similar solution on my recyclerView and put three icons on upper right corner that appear after longClick –

Comment: Thanks a lot dear Mark Murphy @CommonsWare. Your books are the best ever written on Android. Trust me when I tell you that your books proven to be very valuable for an android programmer, especially when it needs. Thanks a lot!!!!!!
I have a deep esteem of your work.

Comment: @HoudeBarsali: "You are telling that it is not possible?" -- I am telling you that there is no standard solution for what you are seeking. "at the moment I am opening calling Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT" -- that is equivalent to the file-open dialogs that you see in desktop operating systems. It is not really a file manager, where users can do what they want. And thanks for the kind words!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Android 11+ devices:

```
String folder = "Documents";

String scheme = "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3A" + folder;

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(scheme), "vnd.android.document/root"); 

startActivity(intent );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @blackapps, I also created a Document Provider and I solved my problem.
In this way I have a lot of more possibilities like "select all", "compress" etc...